# Symfony: Why is method $this->get() not available in constructor?

Tags: symfony, translation

my constructor of my Controller looks like:

```
function __construct(){#
    var_dump($this->get('translator'));
    exit();
}
```

this will give a `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object`. But why? If I use it inside a action it will work.

Comment: It's quite weird to call `exit();` in a constructor.

Comment: just to isolate from other controller actions...

Comment: Plus, don't you need to call the parent constructor explicitly ?

Comment: I tried it, it will reply a `FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot call constructor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [**Controller**](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.5/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php) method `get` needs the `container` property. Controller extends [**ContainerAware**](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.5/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.php) which has a method `setContainer`. This method let the property `container` be aware of the Container.
Upon instanciation, no method are called, here is the workflow

```
$controller = new MyController($parameters);
$controller->setContainer($container);
```

Before calling __construct, controller has no property `$container`

```
public function __construct($parameters)
{
    var_dump($this->container); // NULL
}
```

So, by calling `$this->get()` you are doing

```
$this->get('translator');
// =
$this->container->get('translator');
// =
null->get('translator');
```

Hence the error.

If you need the validator, you'll have to ask it in your constructor (and respect the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)).
To do so, you'll need to [declare your controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html)

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    my_controller:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Controller\MyController
        arguments:
            - "@translator"
        calls:
            - [ "setContainer", [ "@service_container" ] ]
```

<kbd>**routing.yml**</kbd>

```
bar_route:
    path: /bar
    defaults: { _controller: my_controller:barAction }
```

<kbd>**MyController**</kbd>

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    protected $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll search for a way to realize this with translator.

Answer (score 2):

Base controller's method `get()` is a shortcut for `$this->container->get($id);`. `$this->container` is set in one of the controller's parent - `abstract class ContainerAware`. So,
until object construction is finished, there is no `Controller` object that would have `get()` method. In general, `container` is not available in `Controller`'s constructor.

Comment: But if I call the parent constructor to finish the construction it will also not work.

Comment: It will not work. This is the fact, `container` is not available in `Controller`'s constructor.