# Symfony Forwarding / Retriving result from another controller returns nothing

Tags: php, symfony

I made two bundles. I have created an action method in each of their respective controllers.

I am trying to get result of A in B.

I have attempted to include the content of the view of what A generates in B but my include ends up missing a variable therefore I retrieve the result from forwarding it.

I read the documentation and decided to use `$variable=$this->forwad(MyControllerA)` but my `$variable` doesn't get any result when I read the data in the view.

I was wondering as I found no similar issue if I am doing something wrong or if I should do this differently.

**Code**

```
public function getAAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $list_A = $em->getRepository('ABundle:A_Entity')->findAll();

    return $list_A;
}

public function getBAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $list_B = $em->getRepository('PropertyBundle:B_Entity')->findAll();

    $list_A = $this->forward('A_Bundle:A_Entity:getA');

    return $this->render('@B/B/getB.html.twig', array('list_B' => $list_B, 'list_A' => $list_A));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more lengthy sample of your code?

Comment: Could you attach your A code and provide the result of `dump($variable)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out i was wrong.

I dumped the variable as suggested by @Rendy and did way deeper research to try and understand more. it averred that forward works with response.

From there i tried manipulating the response i got but due to my lack of knowledge and despite the research i couldn't find how to retrieve the array i sent.

Therefore i converted my controller into service as follow in `services.yml` of my bundle

```
    services:
   bundle_a:
       class: BundleA\Controller\AController
       calls:
                   - [ "setContainer", [ "@service_container" ] ]
```

If you're wondering about the last line its because when calling the container is null. That line fixed it.
For more info you can look at [Symfony: Why is method $this->get() not available in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267115/symfony-why-is-method-this-get-not-available-in-constructor)

Then i just called my method in the `B Controller` as follow

```
$list_a= $this->get('bundle_a')->getAAction();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$variable=$this->forwad(MyBundle:MyControllerA:myAction)` and not `$variable=$this->forwad(MyControllerA)`

http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html

Show us the code so you can get better help